# Copying shared pointer's attirbute to another shared pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I have a quick question about shared pointers since i'm facing an issue related to shared pointers.
I have a shared pointer called **Cube** which has a vector of shared pointers of **Vector3d**.

What i want to do is to create another **Cube** object that has the same vector of shared pointers of **Vector3d**, so they have the same vector with the same Vector3d. However when i do this it creates a reference to each **Vector3d** in the vector for the second **Cube** object. This means that whenever i change the points in the second **Cube** it changes all the Vector3d in the first **Cube** too.

**Cube class:**

```
class Cube
{
public:
Cube();
~Cube();
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CVector3d>> vectors;
void calculate_center();
double center_x;
double center_y;
double center_z;
std::vector<int> indices;
void transform(std::shared_ptr<CMatrix3d> transformation_matrix);
};
```

**Both Cube objects and the assignation of the Vector3d collection:**

```
std::shared_ptr<GameObject> cube_3d = std::make_shared<Cube>();
cube_3d->vectors.push_back(std::make_shared<CVector3d>(300, 100, 0));       //front top left
cube_3d->vectors.push_back(std::make_shared<CVector3d>(300, 100, -200));        //back top left
cube_3d->vectors.push_back(std::make_shared<CVector3d>(500, 100, -200));        //back top right
cube_3d->vectors.push_back(std::make_shared<CVector3d>(500, 100, 0));       //front top right
cube_3d->vectors.push_back(std::make_shared<CVector3d>(300, 300, 0));       //front bottom left
cube_3d->vectors.push_back(std::make_shared<CVector3d>(300, 300, -200));        //back bottom left
cube_3d->vectors.push_back(std::make_shared<CVector3d>(500, 300, -200));        //back bottom right
cube_3d->vectors.push_back(std::make_shared<CVector3d>(500, 300, 0));       //front bottom right

std::shared_ptr<GameObject> projection_cube_3d = std::make_shared<Cube>();
projection_cube_3d->vectors = cube_3d->vectors;
```

How can i solve this and is this a design-flaw in my code?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1: Added the actual code snippets**

Comment: Google "shallow copy" vs. "deep copy"

Comment: Why are you even using shared pointers if you don't what your things to be shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `projection_cube_3d->vectors = cube_3d->vectors;` does a copy assignment, which replaces the contents of the vector with copies of the contents of the other vector. In other words, each shared_ptr in `cube_3d->vectors` is copied into `projection_cube_3d->vectors`. Of course, copying a shared_ptr doesn't create a copy of the object pointed by the shared_ptr, the two pointers point at the same object (that's the whole point of the shared_ptr in the first place).

What you want to do is to create a copy of each CVector3D. You can do this with the following code:

```
for (auto& ptr : cube_3d->vectors)
    projection_cube_3d->vectors.push_back(std::make_shared<CVector3D>(*ptr))
```

The code `std::make_shared<CVector3D>(*ptr)` creates a new CVector3D which is a copy of `*ptr`, and wraps the pointer to the new object in a shared_ptr, which then you push into your vector.

As pointed out in the comments, you should consider writing a copy constructor for Cube, which does a deep copy instead of a shallow copy. Also note that shared_ptr should be used only when necessary, when you need to express shared ownership. In your case I don't believe this is needed, an example of that is that you want each cube to store its own `CVector3D`s. Also it only makes sense to use pointers to CVector3D if you intend to use this object polymorphically, (e.g. it has subclasses with different behaviours) or if it is a big, complex object that you truly don't want it to be copied around. This is rarely the case for such primitive type as a vector3d, therefore probably you don't need pointers. A `std::vector<CVector3D>` will be better, in which case the copy-assignment of one vector to another, will automatically do the thing you intended.